# Can a power series uniformly converge on open disc?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Does there exist a power series of radius of convergence $R$ that uniformly converges on the open disc of radius $R$?

Intuitively, I do not think this is the case since there would be a singularity at some point on $|z|=R$, and so when we get near there, the series tends towards infinity and there is no way for the series to converge uniformly. But I have heard from others that the answer is that such a power series does in fact exist.

Comment: Sure $\sum z^n/n^2, n \ge 1$; the singularity at $1$ is not isolated; function is continuous on the unit disc; with more care we can make it infinitely differentiable on the circle too (as one variable there or as limit from inside of derivatives)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ has radius of convergence $1$ and it converges uniformly on $\overline{D(0,1)}$; in particular, it converges uniformly on $D(0,1)$.

Comment: Is the best way to see this from the $M$-test?

Comment: That's how I would do it.